# Switch product key windows 10 home and pro

Tags: windows, windows-10, license, product-key

I've got today windows 8.1 pro on my workstation and windows 8.1 home on my laptop. I've upgraded each of them to windows 10 (pro on workstation and home on laptop) last month.

However, I need now pro (hyper v) on my laptop and not on my workstation. I'd like to switch these licenses : to set the pro license on my laptop, and the home license on my workstation.

Is that feasible?

I'm troubled because I've read that the licenses of windows 10 are linked to the motherboard. Can a clean install help me here?

Edit:

Found that on http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/Useterms/Retail/Windows/10/UseTerms_Retail_Windows_10_English.htm

Answer : moving the stand-alone software from my workstation is legal but not the software preinstalled on my laptop

> Transfer. The provisions of this section do not apply if you acquired
>   the software as a consumer in Germany or in any of the countries
>   listed on this site (aka.ms/transfer), in which case any transfer of
>   the software to a third party, and the right to use it, must comply
>   with applicable law.
>
> a.      Software preinstalled on device. If you acquired the software
>   preinstalled on a device (and also if you upgraded from software
>   preinstalled on a device), you may transfer the license to use the
>   software directly to another user, only with the licensed device. The
>   transfer must include the software and, if provided with the device,
>   an authentic Windows label including the product key. Before any
>   permitted transfer, the other party must agree that this agreement
>   applies to the transfer and use of the software.
>
> b.      Stand-alone software. If you acquired the software as
>   stand-alone software (and also if you upgraded from software you
>   acquired as stand-alone software), you may transfer the software to
>   another device that belongs to you. You may also transfer the software
>   to a device owned by someone else if (i) you are the first licensed
>   user of the software and (ii) the new user agrees to the terms of this
>   agreement. You may use the backup copy we allow you to make or the
>   media that the software came on to transfer the software. Every time
>   you transfer the software to a new device, you must remove the
>   software from the prior device. You may not transfer the software to
>   share licenses between devices.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the Windows 10 Upgrade EULA, it states that licences are not transferable and last for the lifetime of the machine it is installed on.

So, **legally, the answer is no**.

Sorry I could not be of more help, but I don't want a lawsuit from Microsoft.

Also, a clean install requires a retail licence key, not the one used to upgrade your Windows disto.